# Console application does not show after upgrading TFM

Tags: asp.net-core, console-application

Although what I am trying to achieve is met but my console does not appear after updating from

> net5.0

to

> net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0

I am trying to get a toast notification that's why I had to upgrade the TFM. Below is in my `.csproj` file that I changed

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>false</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your OS version, the issue might relate the OS version and the TargetFramework doesn't match.

`net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0`: Use this value if your app targets **Windows 10, version 1809**.
`net5.0-windows10.0.18362.0`: Use this value if your app targets **Windows 10, version 1903**.
`net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0`: Use this value if your app targets **Windows 10, version 2004**.

More detail information, see [.NET 5: Use the Target Framework Moniker option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance#net-5-use-the-target-framework-moniker-option)

Comment: Yes Sir. I actually was able to resolve this issue. It is the version that I was using.